# make: .SECONDARY target breaks buld

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target

My target is to generate a file (MyOut.elf) and, **if this file is generated**, generate other two files (MyOut.s19 and size.txt) that are dependent on the that file.

I'm quite a newbie on makefiles, but I wrote the following:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := full

full: MyOut.elf MyOut.s19 size.txt
    @echo TARGET

# Tool invocations
MyOut.s19: MyOut.elf
    @echo 'Building S19 : $@'
    @echo 'MyOut.s19: MyOut.elf' > MyOut.s19
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

size.txt: MyOut.elf
    @echo 'Building section size summary : $@'
    @echo 'size.txt: MyOut.elf' > size.txt
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '


all: MyOut.elf

MyOut.elf:
    @echo 'Building ELF: $@'
    @echo 'MyOut.elf' > MyOut.elf
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

.PHONY: full
#.SECONDARY:
```

Now, if I run `make`, everything works as expected:

```
> make
Building ELF: MyOut.elf
Finished building target: MyOut.elf

Building S19 : MyOut.s19
Finished building target: MyOut.s19

Building section size summary : size.txt
Finished building target: size.txt

TARGET
```

Instead, if I **uncomment** the last line `.SECONDARY:`, the dependency chain seems "broken", as it stops after the first target (MyOut.elf):

```
> del *.elf                                

> make                                     
Building ELF: MyOut.elf                    
Finished building target: MyOut.elf        

TARGET
```

Then, if I run make again, the dependent files `MyOut.s19` and `size.txt` are built:

```
> make                                     
Building S19 : MyOut.s19                   
Finished building target: MyOut.s19        

Building section size summary : size.txt   
Finished building target: size.txt         

TARGET
```

So, my questions are:

- Why is this happening?
- How can I overcome this problem? (Note: I can't remove the .SECONDARY directive, since this is part of a makefile automatically generated by Eclipse)

Comment: When you remove `*.elf`, what happens if you also remove the two other files from the previous make run?

Comment: @Kusalananda: if I remove all the output files, all three are rebuilt correctly.

Comment: ... and if you uncomment `.SECONDARY:`, delete the `elf` file and run make, all are rebuilt?

Comment: @Kusalananda: yes, as stated in the first example. The problem is that (as I mentioned) I can't remove `.SECONDARY`, as this is an auto generated makefile

Comment: This looks wrong to me.  I suggest you bring it up as a possible bug on the bug-make@gnu.org mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this: I added a new "dummy" target `otherTargets` to the prerequisites of the target `full`:

```
full: MyOut.elf otherTargets
otherTargets: MyOut.s19 size.txt
```

Now, when I run `make`, I get

```
Building ELF: MyOut.elf
Finished building target: MyOut.elf

Building section size summary : size.txt
Finished building target: size.txt

Building S19 : MyOut.s19
Finished building target: MyOut.s19
```

And if I run it for the second time, I get

```
make: Nothing to be done for `full'.
```

Nonetheless, if I erase the `.elf` file, the "dependant" files are rebuilt correctly.

The explanation to this I found is related to the [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules):

> If an ordinary file b does not exist, and make considers a target that depends on b, it invariably creates b and then updates the target from b. But if b is an intermediate file, then make can leave well enough alone. It won’t bother updating b, or the ultimate target, unless some prerequisite of b is newer than that target or there is some other reason to update that target.

Therefore, my "intermediate files" `MyOut.s19` and `size.txt` are not rebuilt.
My solution is then working since the target `otherTargets` is never generating an output file, therefore it always needs update.